# Sort a list of tuples using index position of items in another list

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, tuples

I have a base list.

```
li = ['fca', 'fc_add', 'fca_2', 'fcadd_2', 'Red_Exis', 'G_Exis', 'P_Exis',
      'fam_1']
```

and want to use the index position of items in the list to sort the following list of tuples.

```
tup= [('G_Exis','abc'), ('fca','210Y'), ('Red_Exis', 107),
      ('fc_add','999 Des ST.')]
```

I need the final sorted list to look like the following:

```
fin_tup = [('fca','210Y'), ('fc_add','999 Des ST.'), ('Red_Exis', 107), 
           ('G_Exis','abc')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to not actually sort it, but store it in a dictionary using the indices of the key on which you are sorting as the dictionary keys :

```
>>> d ={}
>>> for i in tup : d[li.index(i[0])] = i
>>> list(d.values())
[('fca', '210Y'), ('fc_add', '999 Des ST.'), ('Red_Exis', 107), ('G_Exis', 'abc')]
```

*This is the easy way, not the efficient one.*

Comment: In addition to being O(n**2) it also depends on you `d.values()`'s order which is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

```
index_dict = {item: index for index, item in enumerate(li)}
tup.sort(key=lambda t: index_dict[t[0]])
print(tup)
```

#### Output

```
[('fca', '210Y'), ('fc_add', '999 Des ST.'), ('Red_Exis', 107),
 ('G_Exis', 'abc')]
```

Or without sorting:

```
index_dict = {item: index for index, item in enumerate(li)}

fin_tup = [None]*len(li)
for t in tup:
    fin_tup[index_dict[t[0]]] = t
fin_tup = [t for t in fin_tup if t is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sort()'s key parameter. The value of the sorting is the index in li, so pluck out the first item from each value, and find the index in li. Done.

```
tup.sort(key=lambda item_in_li, trash: li.index(item_in_li))
```